# How do I convert month-day to ordinal date/julian day in R?

Tags: r

I am using this to convert date to Julian day/day of the year

```
df$julday <- yday(ymd(df$DATE))
```

where `df$DATE = 19620701`

However, I also want to do the same when I have month and day only (no year). I know how to do it when I have all three.

```
   DATE
   0101
   0102
   0103
```

Expected output

```
   JDAY
   1
   2
   3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
yday( as.Date("0102", "%m%d") )
```